# Error receiving broadcast Intent?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Below is my `BroadcastReceiver` code where I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=org.mosquitto.android.powerviewer.PING flg=0x4 (has extras)
```

My code:

```
public class PingSender extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        context2 = context;

        try {
            System.err.println("MQTT IS NULLLLLLLLLLLLL");
            mqttClient.ping();
        } catch (MqttException e) {

            Log.e("mqtt", "ping failed - MQTT exception", e);

            try {
                mqttClient.disconnect();
            } catch (MqttPersistenceException e1) {
                Log.e("mqtt", "disconnect failed - persistence exception", e1);
            }

            // reconnect
            if (connectToBroker()) {
                String deviceID = mPrefs.getString(PREF_DEVICE_ID, null);
                ;
                deviceID = MQTT_CLIENT_ID + "/" + deviceID;
                subscribeToTopic(deviceID);
            }
        }

        // start the next keep alive period
        scheduleNextPing();
    }
}
```

Comment: The first thing I'd check is the changes you've made against the original version of the code. It's possible the error is there as well, but it's worth checking. I'd also point out that you should probably update your package naming so it isn't identical to the demo (I doubt this is for viewing home power usage) and in your own domain.

Answer (score 0):

Look out if you are overriding any Android lifecycle events and properly call the base class constructors as requried.

Comment: Thanks for ur response..and i'm doing everything correct and i'm not getting this error frequently..out of 1000 users only 20 to 30 user are getting this error and i'm unable to replicate this error on my device...!

Comment: And i'm using this in service of my push notification class